# Functioning of Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to install the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows for Powershell. So far I have not been able to find a combination of the Sign-In Assistant and Powershell module versions that allows me to create a connection in a Powershell session. My measure for success has been to run the Connect-MsolService cmdlet to create such a connection. I have tried it both from the command line and in a script. The (few) forum and blogs posts that reference this functionality have been very contradictory.

I am using the same credentials that I use to log into manage.windowsazure.com.

As to the specifics I have the following configuration:

- Windows Server 2012R2
- Powershell version 4.0 ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)
- Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant version 7.250.4556.0
- Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows Azure version
  1.0.8362. The version number is based on the command (get-item                           C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion

My questions are as follows:

1. What versions work on Windows Server 2012R2?
2. Is there a specific .Net version that I might be missing?
3. Am I looking at it wrong? For example is the cmdlet
   Connect-MsolService not the metric to be using? Is there another way
   that I might verify that I have a connection?

My understanding is that the Powershell cmdlets, as well as all the other methods for managing Azure, are based on the REST API's. Would that be a better way to go? Of course I would not be able to dynamically enter commands, but I would be able to validate credentials etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to authenicate with an MSA account? Try connecting with a Global Admin AAD account (eg. globaladminuser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com).